# Only 5GHz wireless in new ubuntu 16.04 installation

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, atheros

I have a problem with a new installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. All is working except the wireless card. In fact my atheros card can only connect and see 5 Ghz networks. Unfortunately I have a 2,4 Ghz connection at work and I can't connect my pc to the AP.

Now the driver in use on my pc should be ath10k. (I see it using lsmod)

This is the ouput of the suggested commands:

$ sudo lshw -class network

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0.1
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
   logical name: enp2s0f1
   version: 12
   serial: 98:29:a6:4a:6e:fd
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:280 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b4204000-b4204fff memory:b4200000-b4203fff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Qualcomm Atheros
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 31
   serial: 98:22:ef:87:09:d5
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.13.0-38-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 ip=192.168.1.204 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:283 memory:b4000000-b41fffff
```

$ lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5914 (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5917 (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 174d (rev ff)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 31)
```

$ rfkill list all

```
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

$ iwlist wlp3s0 frequency

```
wlp3s0    31 channels in total; available frequencies :
      Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
      Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
      Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
      Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
      Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
      Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
      Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
      Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
      Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
      Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
      Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
      Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
      Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
      Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
      Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
      Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
      Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
      Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
      Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
      Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
      Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
      Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
      Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
      Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
      Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
      Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
      Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
      Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
      Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
      Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
      Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
      Channel 144 : 5.72 GHz
```

$ dmesg | grep ath

```
[    3.293727] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    3.597659] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 target 0x05020001 chip_id 0x003821ff sub 11ad:08a6
[    3.597664] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    3.598275] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 api 5 features ignore-otp crc32 79cea2c7
[    3.661724] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 93da0176
[    4.143442] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    4.150168] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x69
[    4.150169] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    4.150170] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    4.150171] ath: Regpair used: 0x69
[    4.156612] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   14.795230] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[   14.795231] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[   14.795232] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[   14.795233] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[   14.795234] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[   14.795235] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[   14.795236] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
[  892.259038] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  931.607523] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[  931.607525] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[  931.607527] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[  931.607529] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[  931.607531] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[  931.607533] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[  931.607535] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
[ 1959.785016] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 1959.785340] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 1959.785845] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 1959.786365] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 1959.786952] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 1959.787524] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 1959.887516] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 1959.989892] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 1959.990116] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 1960.092261] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 1962.196130] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[ 1962.196131] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[ 1962.196132] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[ 1962.196133] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[ 1962.196134] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[ 1962.196135] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[ 1962.196136] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
[ 6201.973136] ath10k_warn: 21 callbacks suppressed
[ 6201.973143] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 6225.937178] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 6225.942629] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 6225.997103] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 6226.099684] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 6226.202324] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 6226.304302] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 6226.406673] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 6226.509506] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 6226.713934] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 6226.919156] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 6231.550553] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[ 6231.550557] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[ 6231.550558] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[ 6231.550560] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[ 6231.550562] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[ 6231.550564] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[ 6231.550566] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
[ 6823.445195] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 6823.450209] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 6823.503900] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 6823.606284] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 6823.708700] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 6823.811528] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 6823.913534] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 6828.557009] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[ 6828.557012] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[ 6828.557014] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[ 6828.557016] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[ 6828.557018] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[ 6828.557019] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[ 6828.557022] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
[ 7110.122810] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 7157.423307] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 7157.431373] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 7162.125108] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[ 7162.125111] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[ 7162.125112] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[ 7162.125114] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[ 7162.125116] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[ 7162.125118] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[ 7162.125120] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
[ 7640.923598] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 7640.928706] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 7640.952225] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 7645.635496] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[ 7645.635499] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[ 7645.635501] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[ 7645.635503] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[ 7645.635505] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[ 7645.635507] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[ 7645.635511] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
[ 8225.186946] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 8225.249337] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 8229.899811] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[ 8229.899814] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[ 8229.899816] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[ 8229.899818] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[ 8229.899820] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[ 8229.899821] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[ 8229.899824] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
[ 8375.324490] ath9k: ath9k: Driver unloaded
[14023.578200] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[14045.340287] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[14045.345449] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[14045.389956] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[14050.049797] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[14050.049799] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[14050.049801] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[14050.049803] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[14050.049806] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[14050.049807] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[14050.049809] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
[17011.252111] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[17011.320417] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[17015.953793] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[17015.953797] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[17015.953800] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[17015.953802] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[17015.953805] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[17015.953807] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[17015.953810] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
[19396.782305] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[19396.787164] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[19396.844010] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[19401.481533] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[19401.481536] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[19401.481539] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[19401.481542] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[19401.481545] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[19401.481547] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[19401.481550] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
[20053.334076] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[20068.521093] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[20068.595634] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[20073.225841] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[20073.225844] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[20073.225846] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[20073.225848] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[20073.225850] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[20073.225852] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[20073.225854] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
```

I think that the problem is that the system recognise only wifi 802.ac and not 802.b/g/n

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76412/discussion-on-question-by-christian-vari-only-5ghz-wireless-in-new-ubuntu-16-04).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upgrade the firmware you can do:

```
cd ~
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
cd ath10k-firmware/QCA9377/hw1.0/CNSS.TF.1.0
mv /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin.orig
sudo cp firmware-5.bin_CNSS.TF.1.0-00267-QCATFSWPZ-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
```

Then try rebooting.

[I had no choice to move this out of comments so it would fit.]